# Iterate over two images pixel by pixel in Numpy (with a random condition)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, vectorization

```
import random
def sp_noise(image,prob):
    '''
    Add salt and pepper noise to image
    prob: Probability of the noise
    '''
    output = np.zeros(image.shape,np.uint8)
    thres = 1 - prob 
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            rdn = random.random()
            if rdn < prob:
                output[i][j] = 0
            elif rdn > thres:
                output[i][j] = 255
            else:
                output[i][j] = image[i][j]
    return output
```

That's what I want to achieve. I understand that this function doesn't use vectorization, but I don't see how I could get rid of the loops in this case. If there were a condition for pixel values, that would be trivial. But in this case there is no condition on indices or pixel values, I just need to either preserve the pixel value or, depending on the value of the random variable, set it to 0 or 1.

How do I vectorize that?

Comment: Please do *not* iterate with numpy arrays.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I know it's disastrous. I just don't know how to avoid iterating here.

Comment: try 'numpy.ndenumerate'. Exemple: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html

Comment: Normally, you are only going to add salt and pepper to relatively few pixels, so you could work out how many pixels you want to affect (multiply probability by width * height) and iterate that many times generating for each a random [x,y] location and then add salt or pepper to your original image at that location depending whether another random number comes up greater or less than 0.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [`np.random.random`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html) with an additional `size` parameter to get a whole array of random floats. Then, use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to access all the pixels matching one of the conditions.

That'd be my solution, including [OpenCV](https://www.opencv.org) for image loading and display and some simple performance analysis:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

def sp_noise(image, prob):
    output = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
    thres = 1 - prob
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            rdn = np.random.random()
            if rdn < prob:
                output[i][j] = 0
            elif rdn > thres:
                output[i][j] = 255
            else:
                output[i][j] = image[i][j]
    return output

def sp_noise_vec(image, prob):
    output = image.copy()
    thres = 1 - prob
    rdn = np.random.random(image.shape[:2])
    output[np.where(rdn < prob)] = 0
    output[np.where(rdn > thres)] = 255
    return output

img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')

tic = time.perf_counter()
out = sp_noise(img, 0.1)
toc = time.perf_counter()
print('Duration loop: ', toc - tic)

tic = time.perf_counter()
out_vec = sp_noise_vec(img, 0.1)
toc = time.perf_counter()
print('Duration vectorized: ', toc - tic)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('out', out)
cv2.imshow('out_vec', out_vec)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Image outputs are comparable. For some `400 x 400` RGB image, I get the following times:

```
Duration loop:        0.21099094100000004
Duration vectorized:  0.004011090000000106
```

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.1.2
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this gives exactly the same result - as there is a possibility (extremely small) that you could hit a pixel with salt and then the same pixel again again with pepper - but I tried a different approach. It also generates exactly half salt and half pepper, which other solutions will tend to only do when averaged over a large amount of samples. Maybe the speed and memory savings are worth the inaccuracy - YMMV :-)

First determine how many pixels will be affected by noise, call it `N`. Then generate N/2 pairs of [x,y] coordinates and set the corresponding pixel in the output image black, then generate another N/2 pairs of [x,y] coordinates and set those to white.

```
import numpy as np

def me(image,prob): 
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    # Number of noise affected pixels
    N = int(w * h * prob)
    # Half salt
    image[np.random.randint(0,h,int(N/2)), np.random.randint(0,w,int(N/2))] = 255
    # Half pepper
    image[np.random.randint(0,h,int(N/2)), np.random.randint(0,w,int(N/2))] = 0 
    return image 

# Make solid grey start image
image = np.full((400,400), 128, dtype=np.uint8)
```

With `p=0.1` and `p=0.01`, I get:

```
%timeit me(image,0.1)                                                                               
296 µs ± 2.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit me(image,0.01)                                                                              
42.2 µs ± 933 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn't `image[np.random.randint(0,h,int(N/2)), np.random.randint(0,w,int(N/2))] = 255` be `image[np.random.randint(0,w,int(N/2)), np.random.randint(0,h,int(N/2))] = 255`?

Comment: @DonDraper No, I don't think so. You give vertical axis first in Numpy. Check by making the image 20x800 and it will quickly go wrong and die in a heap if they are the wrong way around :-)

Comment: It doesn't work for my image with shape (372, 1412) so I made the conclusion that the order should be reversed. Can you please test it on an image with shape, say, (100,400)?

Comment: D'oh! Sorry, you are right, it should be `h, w = image.shape[:2]` I have corrected my answer.